# some directions/hints with a coding challenge in JS

Tags: javascript, class, data-structures

Ive got a challenge to submit (no automated test/test cases- just a wrriten question) - and I'm not sure I'm doing right (being a noob and all that jazz).

I need to write classes and data structures for a call-center:
It has 3 levels of employees that can take the call;

For each incoming call the system will check who's available- starting at the lowest of the 3 employee levels,
then going up if no employee at that level is free to take the call- till it reaches the 3rd level.

they didn't give me any other instructions so I'm trying to do my best.

That's the code i have so far- what did I miss/should be changed?

```
class CallCenter{
constructor(){
    if (!CallCenter.instance){
        CallCenter.instance = this
        this.callsQueue = []
        this.employees = []
        return this
    }
    return CallCenter.instance
}
addEmployee(emp){
    this.employees.push(emp)
}
addPhoneCall(call){
    this.callsQueue.push(call)
}
dispatchCallDirector(call){
    const emp = this.employees.find(e => e.type === "director" && e.available)
}
dispatchCallManager(call){
    const emp = this.employees.find(e => e.type === "manager" && e.available)
    if (emp){
        emp.getPhoneCall(call, (res) => {
            if (!res){
                this.dispatchCallDirector(call)
            }
        })
    }
}


 dispatchCall(){
        const call = this.callsQueue[0]
        this.callsQueue.splice(0, 1)
        const emp = this.employees.find(e => e.type === "respondent" && e.available)
        if (emp){
            emp.getPhoneCall(call, (res) => {
                if (!res){
                    this.dispatchCallManager(call)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
module.exports = CallCenter

class Employee{
    constructor(type){
        this.available = true
        this.type = type
    }
    set isAvailable(flag){ //available = true or false
        this.available = flag
    }
    get isAvailable() {this.available}
    getPhoneCall(call, report){
        //if employee cant handle the call -
        report(null)
        //if employee can handle the call - this.available = false
    }
}
module.exports = Employee
```

Comment: `get isAvailable() {this.available}` -> `get isAvailable() { return this.available }`

Comment: `dispatchCallDirector(call){ const emp = this.employees.find(e => e.type === "director" && e.available) }` you don't do anything with `emp`

Comment: Thanks for your comment VLAZ, I'm actually only starting to build the solution- so I d'ont have a the working parts in place yet.